# How to modify the HTML outputted by pandoc while converting from docx to HTML?

Tags: python, pandoc

I am using the Pypandoc module of python. The code that I use for converting is:

```
html = pypandoc.convert(
            tmp_loc,
            'html5',
            extra_args=['--extract-media=']
            )
```

This code converts the docx into HTML which is stored in 'html' and at the same time extracts the images from docx and stores them into media repository by the name image01.jpg. The img src in HTML is:

```
<img src="/media/image01.jpg" />
```

Now what I want to do is change the name of the image, that is image01.jpg to a more convenient name. I can easily change the name of the image in the repository. But how do I update the img src tag in the HTML outputted by pypandoc?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd just put each upload in its own directory (`uploadX/index.html` and `uploadX/media/imageY.jpg` etc).

Or else do the renaming at least after the conversion to HTML (much nicer to work with than docx), by e.g. prepending the filenames with a unique id, like `uploadX_imageY.jpg`, and adjusting the links using something like [HTMLParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html).

Comment: Thank you. I used Beautiful soup for modifying the HTML. It worked.

Comment: @ArunabhGhosh great! then feel free to accept and upvote the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is actually connected to docx. In these documents, each image has its own name, even if it's hidden. You can check it in image proprieties - and, automatic name is - of course! - imageXX! So, I suggest changing the names of images in the document itself, and then converting again.

If you have too much images and you want to automate this process somehow, try some hex editor (ghex in linux, I suggest), and "search and replace" function. You can replace "image" by "something", and result files would be "somethingXX.jpg"

Comment: Can I do the above things in python? The situation is that I am asking the user to upload docx files. I recieve the docx files and then I convert it into python. So is there a editor which has a Python module which can search for images and change their names?

Comment: Of course it's possible but i'm not sure if it's really a feature in your case. What do you want to achieve, exactly? Let's say that user named his pictures properly inside his docx - then he gets well-named files. In other case - he gets imageXX stuff. It sounds perfectly OK to me.

Anyway: try https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx

Comment: When the user uploads another file it also has images which have the same name as image01.jpg. So these images replace the previous images. So I wanted to give all the images a unique name myself so that it can't get replaced. Thank you for the above link!!